# Add menu tabs in user edit page

Tags: drupal, menu, drupal-7, themes, user-profile

My main theme is bootstrap 3 and I have couple user roles. Other normal user roles use bootstrap theme, but one user role (not admin) uses seven theme, because I give access to add new content.

I trying to find way how I can add tabs in user profile edit page. And add these tabs only one user role.

I mean this page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPXNy.png

There are two tabs already: /user/id/edit and user/id/edit/main

So how I can add more tabs and links goes custom page where I can add html and php scripts?

Answer (score 0):

For adding new tabs you can use `hook_contextual_links_view_alter` function

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!contextual!contextual.api.php/function/hook_contextual_links_view_alter/7

Inside that function you can alter existing tabs:

```
$element['#links']['bean-']['title'] = 'Edit block';
```

or add new ones, i.e.:

```
 $element['#links']['test'] = array('title' => 'Edit webform',
                                    'href' => 'node/'.$page_id.'/webform',
                                    'query' => array('destination' => substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 4)));
```

So, "trick" is to alter that `$element['#links']` array, which contains current list of tabs.